# Can anyone recommend a series of good training videos for Java

Tags: java, oracle

For someone who is completely new to Java.

Please no old school / ugly video tutorials, something intuitive and easy to learn.

Comment: This isn't really the right sort of question for StackOverflow; as per the FAQ, "we expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise".  This is a matter of opinion IMHO - what makes a video "good"?  What kind of training are you looking for (and saying "everything" doesn't allow for an appropriate answer).  This question would be more appropriate for a discussion forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check these tutorials: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFE2CE09D83EE3E28